# Can I disable DLC in Dead Cells?

Tags: dead-cells

I purchased Dead Cells on Steam with all the DLC and am finding the experience to be overwhelming. Can I disable the DLC to only play with the original content? If yes, how would disabling the DLC impact my existing save file?

Comment: I do not know about impact since I do not own Dead cells, but in general, every steam game that has DLC can disable DLC one by one. ([Uninstalling expansions/DLC, steam community post](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/2451595019866594572/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Sky-AT mentioned](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/402234/can-i-disable-dlc-in-dead-cells#comment564688_402234), you can [disable DLC packs through Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/2451595019866594572/). Below are some things I've observed after disabling DLC:

- Items unlocked from DLC will stop appearing until the DLC is re-enabled. The game will remember which DLC items you've previously found.
- Blueprints for locked DLC items will still be listed when talking to the collector. A red lock will take the place of the item's cell cost.
- Doors to some DLC areas will still be present. If you try to enter one, [a popup will appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1QWS.jpg) saying the DLC is required. You can enable the required DLC mid-run if you want to enter.
- If [Return to Castlevania](https://store.steampowered.com/app/2101430/Dead_Cells_Return_to_Castlevania/) is disabled, the corridor leading to the entrance for Dracula's Castle will not appear.
- The store page for [Rise of the Giant](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1046440/Dead_Cells_Rise_of_the_Giant/) says the new areas will only appear once you've beaten the game at least once, so enabling or disabling it before then will presumably have no effect.